# need to find greatest number in set that's not greater than given variable

Tags: python, loops, indexing, set

I've got a set, weights and an integer desired weight.  I need to remove the element in the list that is closest to, but not greater than desired weight and associate it with actual_weight. Here's what my code looks like thus far:

```
desired_weight = weights[0]
for i in weights:
 for x in weights:
    if x>i:
        if desired_weight <= x:
            actual_weight = desired_weight
            weights.remove()
```

Comment: And what is the actual question?

Comment: If you give some sample inputs and outputs you'll get a lot of more answers here.

Comment: How should duplicates of the target integer be handled?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming I understand what you're asking,

```
actual_weight = max([x for x in weights if x <= desired_weight])
```

Comment: If you also want to remove the weight from the list as you do in your example, you can use: `actual_weight = (lambda x: [x, weights.remove (x) ] [0] ) (max(x for x in weights if x <= desired_weight) )`

Comment: It may be slightly more efficient to pass the generator rather than a list comprehension. Good solution either way, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
desired_weight = weights[0]
diff = inf
actual_weight = 0
for x in weights:
  if x < desired_weight and (x-desired_weight) < diff:
    diff = x - desired_weight
    actual_weight = x

weights.remove(actual_weight)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
actual_weight = max([x for x in weights if x <= desired_weight])
weights.remove(actual_weight)
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please read How [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).